# FuelSDK: use get() to pull salesforce items into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, soap, get, salesforce

I'm attempting to use Salesforce FuelSDK to pull audit items (i.e. click events, unsub events, bounce events, etc.) from our client's Marketing Cloud. I'm sure this is down to my inexperience with APIs, but although I'm able to get a success code from "get()", I'm not sure how to pull the actual content. The end goal is to pull each event type into its own dataframe. Here's what I have so far:

```
import FuelSDK
import ET_Client
import pandas as pd
import requests
 
 
# In[2]:
 
 
#define local variables 
 
clientid= 'client_id_code_here'
clientsecret='client_secret_code_here' 
subdomain = 'mcx1k2thcht5qzdsm6962p8ln2c8'
auth_base_url = f'https://{subdomain}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/'
rest_url = f'https://{subdomain}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/'
soap_url=f'https://{subdomain}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/'
 
 
# In[3]:
 
 
#Passing config as a parameter to ET_Client constructor:
 
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(True, False,
{'clientid': clientid, 
'clientsecret': clientsecret,
'useOAuth2Authentication': 'True',
'authenticationurl': auth_base_url,
'applicationType': 'server',
'baseapiurl': rest_url,
'soapendpoint': soap_url})
 
 
# In[4]:
 
 
# Create an instance of the object type we want to work with:
 
list = FuelSDK.ET_List()
 
 
# In[5]:
 
 
# Associate the ET_Client- object using the auth_stub property:
 
list.auth_stub = myClient
 
 
# In[6]:
 
 
# Utilize one of the ET_List methods:
 
response = list.get()
 
 
# In[7]:
 
 
# Print out the results for viewing
print('Post Status: ' + str(response.status))
print('Code: ' + str(response.code))
print('Message: ' + str(response.message))
print('Result Count: ' + str(len(response.results)))
# print('Results: ' + str(response.results))
 
 
# In[12]:
 
 
debug = False
# stubObj = ET_Client(False, False, params={'clientid': clientid,
#                                                   'clientsecret': clientsecret})
 
getBounceEvent = ET_Client.ET_BounceEvent()
getBounceEvent.auth_stub = myClient
getBounceEvent.props = ["SendID","SubscriberKey","EventDate","Client.ID","EventType","BatchID","TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID","PartnerKey"]
# getBounceEvent.search_filter = {'Property' : 'EventDate', 'SimpleOperator' : 'greaterThan', 'DateValue' : retrieveDate}
getResponse = getBounceEvent.get()
 
 
# In[13]:
 
 
print(getResponse)
 
 
# In[13]:
 
 
#pull data into dataframe
 
df=pd.DataFrame(getResponse)
 
 
# In[52]:
 
 
df.head()
 
 
# In[53]:
 
 
#load data into csv data file
 
df.to_csv('salesforce_bounce_events.csv', index=False)
```

Obviously, "getResponse" is not going to go into a dataframe, since it's just a response code. I know from using other ETL programs that the data is in "Bounce Event" in a tabular format, I just need to know how to pull it from the API. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: how can I run this script on my system? I am unable to import FuelSDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using "getResponse.results"